# How can I print lines from a file to separate files

Tags: perl

I have a file which has lines like this:

```
1       107275  447049 scaffold1443     465     341154  -
```

There are several lines which starts with one, after that a blank line separates and start lines with 2 and so on.
I want to separate these lines to different files based on their number.
I wrote this script but it prints in every file only the first line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#script for choosing chromosome
use strict;

my $filename= $ARGV[0];
open(FILE, $filename);
while (my $line = <FILE>) {
my @data = split('\t', $line);
my $length = @data;
#print $length;
my $num = $data[0];
if ($length ==  6) {
open(my $fh, '>', $num);
print $fh $line;
}
$num = $num + 1;
}
```

please, i need your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `>>` to open file for appending to end of it as `>` always truncates desired file to zero bytes,

```
use strict;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(my $FILE, "<", $filename) or die $!;
while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
  my @data = split('\t', $line);
  my $length = @data;
  #print $length;
  my $num = $data[0];
  if ($length ==  6) {
    open(my $fh, '>>', $num);
    print $fh $line;
  }
  $num = $num + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then *paragraph mode* might be useful.  This breaks a record on two or more new-lines, instead of just one:

```
@ARGV or die "Supply a filename\n";
my $filename= $ARGV[0];

local $/ = "";    # Set paragraph mode
open(my $file, $filename) or die "Unable to open '$filename' for read: $!";

while (my $lines = <$file>) {

    my $num = (split("\t", $lines))[0];

    open(my $fh, '>', $num) or die "Unable to open '$num' for write: $!";
    print $fh $lines;
    close $fh;
}

close $file;
```